# Ecto: How to order results from a certain field in a foreign key

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have a model Ticket which belongs to a User. Every User has many Ticket. So the user_id is a foreign key for every Ticket. How can I build a query that will get me all Tickets ordered by each user's username? I've been trying

```
    query       = from u in User, 
                                        preload: [:tickets]

    query_tickets = from t in Ticket,
                                        order_by: u.username,
                                        preload: [users: ^query]

    tickets = Repo.all(query_tickets)
```

But it says the model Ticket doesn't have any User association?

```
     schema "tickets" do
    field :subject,           :string
    field :body,              :string
    field :followup,          :boolean
    field :closed,            :boolean
    field :file,              :string
    field :filepath,          :map
    belongs_to :user,         UserController
    has_many :ticket_message, TicketMessageController


    timestamps
  end

    schema "users" do 
    field :name,                    :string
    field :username,            :string
    field :password,            :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    field :email,               :string
    field :client,              :string
    field :role,                    :integer
    has_one :services, ServiceController
    has_many :tickets, TicketController

    timestamps
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [preload/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3) here, since preload happens after the query (it will fetch all of the associated ids in its own query) you can't sort on the user_id this way.

From the docs:

```
Repo.all from p in Post, preload: [:comments]
```

> The example above will fetch all posts from the database and then do a separate query returning all comments associated to the given posts.

You have to use a [join/5](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5)

```
query_tickets = from t in Ticket,
  join: u in assoc(t, :user)
  order_by: u.username,

tickets = Repo.all(query_tickets)
```

If you want the users to be set on the `user` key of the tickets (like you get with preload) then you may want to take a look at https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/962

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I had tried that (or something similar before) but I get:

`[error] #PID<0.3814.0> running MyApp.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /index_by_username
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Ecto.QueryError) web/controllers/ticket_controller.ex:44: could not find association `users` on model MyApp.Ticket in query:
`

Comment: `users` should be `user`

Comment: There was also a problem in the models. The associations had the Controller instead of the Models. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: @safm - I didn't actually notice that `Controller` was being used in the schema. Glad you found it.

Comment: Is it possible to sort the tickets after a `tickets = Repo.all(Ticket)`?